# Could this conclusion be expressed as $x$ and not $x^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am refreshing myself on linear algebra after many years, so please bear with me. In the following URL/pdf, on page 7, line (54), the author says the summation is equal to $x^T(\frac{dy}{dz}) + y^T(\frac{dx}{dz})$ (where $^T$ is the matrix transpose operator, not a power operator). My question is, why is this the transpose as opposed to just the vector? In other words, could I also express this as $x(\frac{dy}{dz}) + y(\frac{dy}{dz})$? If not, why not?

[https://atmos.washington.edu/~dennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf](https://atmos.washington.edu/%7Edennis/MatrixCalculus.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

It's given that $x$ and $y$ are column vectors with $n$ rows each. $z$ is also a column vector, with, say, $k$ rows. By convention each derivative $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$ is an $n\times k$ matrix (see Convention 3 in the pdf). You need to transpose both $x$ and $y$ in order to multiply them with $\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}$ respectively. The result will be a $1\times k$ row vector.

Comment: Thank you. That makes perfect sense. Would you be willing to answer a follow-up? I'm having trouble remembering the term scalar as it applies in this situation. Under convention 3, what does it mean for x (or y) to be scalar? My understanding was scalar matrices had to be square. Again, sorry for the basic question-- trying to clear out the cobwebs.

Comment: @Maxthecat 'Scalar' just means real-valued as opposed to vector-valued. A $1\times 1$ matrix is scalar. If $x=(x_1, x_2\ldots,x_n)^T$ is a column vector then $f(x):=x^Tx=\sum_i x_i^2$ is a scalar-valued function of the vector-valued $x$.